# A lot of problem when setting up hawkbit update server

Tags: eclipse-hawkbit

I'm trying to set up hawkBit update server as per https://www.eclipse.org/hawkbit/gettingstarted/ but a lot of issues that I  do not know how to resolve.
The following is summary setup steps:

1. Prerequisites

```
sudo apt install -y default-jre default-jdk
java -version
*openjdk version "11.0.9.1" 2020-11-04*
*OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.9.1+1-Ubuntu-0ubuntu1.18.04)*
*OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.9.1+1-Ubuntu-0ubuntu1.18.04, mixed mode, sharing)*

sudo apt install maven

sudo apt-get -y install mariadb-server
```

2. Download build source code

```
git clone https://github.com/eclipse/hawkbit.git
cd hawkbit
mvn clean install

*Start hawkBit update server*
*Access http://localhost:8080/UI/login to check*
java -jar ./hawkbit-runtime/hawkbit-update-server/target/hawkbit-update-server-0.3.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

3. Customize hawkBit
   3.1. Set up data base

```
sudo mysql -u root
*Welcome to the MariaDB monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.*
*Your MariaDB connection id is 31*
*Server version: 10.1.47-MariaDB-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 Ubuntu 18.04*
*Copyright (c) 2000, 2018, Oracle, MariaDB Corporation Ab and others.*
*Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.*

MariaDB [(none)]> USE mysql;
*Reading table information for completion of table and column names*
*You can turn off this feature to get a quicker startup with -A*
*Database changed*
MariaDB [mysql]> CREATE USER 'test'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '123456a@';
*Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)*
*MariaDB [mysql]> UPDATE user SET authentication_string=password('123456a@') where user='test';*
*Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)*
*Rows matched: 1  Changed: 0  Warnings: 0*

MariaDB [mysql]> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'test'@'localhost';
*Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)*

MariaDB [mysql]> UPDATE user SET plugin='mysql_native_password' WHERE User='test';
*Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)*
*Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0*

MariaDB [mysql]> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
*Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)*

MariaDB [mysql]> CREATE DATABASE hawkbit;
*Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)*

MariaDB [mysql]> ALTER DATABASE hawkbit COLLATE latin1_bin;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [mysql]> grant all privileges on hawkbit.* TO 'test'@'localhost' identified by '123456a@';
*Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)*

MariaDB [(none)]> exit
*Bye*

sudo service mysql restart
```

Append the following code to hawkbit-runtime/hawkbit-update-server/pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mariadb.jdbc</groupId>
    <artifactId>mariadb-java-client</artifactId>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

Override the following code to hawkbit-runtime/hawkbit-update-server/src/main/resources/application-mysql.properties:

```
spring.jpa.database=mysql
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hawkbit
spring.datasource.username=test
spring.datasource.password=123456a@
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver
```

Application.properties is appended with new URL:

```
server.hostname=http://<my_ip_addr>   
server.port=<my_port>
```

Rebuild and run:

```
cd hawkbit
mvn clean install
java -jar ./hawkbit-runtime/hawkbit-update-server/target/hawkbit-update-server-0.3.0-SNAPSHOT.jar --spring.profiles.active=mysql
```

Open http://<my_ip_addr>:<my_port>, I cannot log in by "admin" username and "admin" password.

Run hawkBit without --spring.profiles.active=mysql, I succeed to log in by admin, admin.
Even the application.properties is kept unchanged, the results are the same.

I try to comment out all User Security:

```
# spring.security.user.name=admin
# spring.security.user.password={noop}admin-pwd
# spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true
```

and uncomment Define own users instead of default "admin" user:

```
hawkbit.server.im.users[0].username=test
hawkbit.server.im.users[0].password={noop}123456a@
hawkbit.server.im.users[0].firstname=Huong
hawkbit.server.im.users[0].lastname=Ha
hawkbit.server.im.users[0].permissions=ALL
```

the build failed with the following log:

```
[INFO] hawkBit :: Runtime :: Update Server ................ FAILURE [  7.579 s]
[INFO] hawkBit :: Test Report ............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  14:59 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-12-26T16:47:05+07:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.22.1:test (default-test) on project hawkbit-update-server: There are test failures.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Please refer to /home/huong/software-update-server/hawkbit/hawkbit-runtime/hawkbit-update-server/target/surefire-reports for the individual test results.
```

So I have some questions and hope someone could help:

1. The exact steps to setup hawkBit update server. Any experiences would be helpful
2. The hawkbit database (is created as above) is an empty database, do you have an database which is compatible with hawkBit?

Thanks,
Huong Ha

Comment: A docker image is not  an option for you?

Comment: I don't think Hawkbit support Java 11 since they have an issue open ( https://github.com/eclipse/hawkbit/issues/955 ) for Java 11 support. Though it might work since most of the Java 11 issues seem to be non build / run related.

Comment: I need to adapt new use name/password as well as run in external (not localhost), so I think I have to start with source code.

Answer (score 1):

The procedure you are following is quite correct. However, there are couple of remarks regarding your approach:

1. You can omit running all the tests while building Hawkbit by specifying `skipTests` maven argument: `mvn clean install -DskipTests`. It will drastically decrease the build time.
2. You don't need to modify the `application.properties` in order to use MySQL database. Instead just specify the `--spring.profiles.active=mysql` program argument for activating the "mysql" Spring profile and adapt the `application-mysql.properties` as needed (in your case changing the username and password datasource config).
3. You need to either use the `spring.security.user.name` and `spring.security.user.password` or `hawkbit.server.im.users`, not **both**. Spring security user should work out of the box. Additionally, you should NOT comment out `spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true`, it is responsible for the bean overriding mechanism of Spring and has nothing to do with Spring Security.
4. Hawkbit is using Flyway DB version control (https://flywaydb.org) meaning that it will execute all of the required DB migration scripts during the application start.
5. And yes, you can run Hawkbit with java11 (see https://github.com/eclipse/hawkbit/commit/ed9a4b1bb31f4cd996e8af8867d67cdcda682d00)

Hope that brings you further ;)

Comment: Thanks, Bogdan. Your comment is helpful in some aspects. But I still can't log in to the hawkBit. Could you please see my comment and help?

Comment: Hi @Bogdan, I've edited the question as per your comment. But the problem is persistent.
Run hawkBit

With --spring.profiles.active=mysql
=> Can't log in by admin, admin
Without --spring.profiles.active=mysql
=> Log in OK.