# hawkBit swupdate Suricatta: HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized

Tags: swupdate, eclipse-hawkbit

I want to set up hawkBit (running on server) and swupdate (running on multiple clients - Linux OS) to perform OS/Software update in Suricatta mode.

1/ Follow up [my post on hawkBit community](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65455267/a-lot-of-problem-when-setting-up-hawkbit-update-server), I've succeeded to run hawkBit in my server as below:

- Exported to external link: http://:
- Enabled MariaDB
- Enabled Gateway Token Authentication (in hawkBit system configuration)
- Created a software module
- Uploaded an artifact
- Created a distribution set
- Assigned the software module to the distribution set
- Create Targets (in Deployment Mangement UI) with Targets ID is "dev01"
- Created a Rollout
- Created a Target Filter

2/ I've succeeded to build/execute swupdate as [SWupdate guideline](https://sbabic.github.io/swupdate/building-with-yocto.html)

- Enabled Suricatta daemon mode
- Run swupdate: `/usr/bin/swupdate -v -k /etc/public.pem -u '-t DEFAULT -u http://<domain>:<port> -i dev01'`
- I'm pretty sure this command isn't correct, output log as below:

```
*   Trying <ip address>...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to <domain> (<ip address>) port <port> (#0)
> GET /DEFAULT/controller/v1/10 HTTP/1.1
Host: <domain>:<port>
User-Agent: libcurl-agent/1.0
Content-Type: application/json
Accept: application/json
charsets: utf-8

< HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
< Date: Sun, 16 May 2021 02:43:40 GMT
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
< Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
< Pragma: no-cache
< Expires: 0
< X-Frame-Options: DENY
< Content-Length: 0
< 
* Connection #0 to host <domain> left intact
[TRACE] : SWUPDATE running :  [channel_log_effective_url] : Channel's effective URL resolved to http://<domain>:<port>/DEFAULT/controller/v1/dev01
[ERROR] : SWUPDATE failed [0] ERROR corelib/channel_curl.c : channel_get : 1109 : Channel operation returned HTTP error code 401.
[DEBUG] : SWUPDATE running :  [suricatta_wait] : Sleeping for 45 seconds.
```

- As per a suggestion from @laverman on [Gitter](https://gitter.im/eclipse/hawkbit?at=5def3f5d6a85195b9e2dd0d1):

```
You can use Gateway token in the Auth header of the request, e.g. “Authorization : GatewayToken a56cacb7290a8d8a96a2f149ab2f23d1”
```

but I don't know how the client sends this request (it should be sent by swupdate, right?)

3/ Follow up these instructions from [Tutorial @ EclipseCon Europe 2019](https://stefbehl.github.io/hawkbit-101/#/), it guides me to send the request to provision multiple clients from hawkBit Device Simulator. And the problem is how to apply this to real devices.

Another confusion is: when creating new Software Module, Distribution on hawkBit UI, I can't find the ID of these, but creating by send request as Tutorial, I can see the IDs in the response.

So my questions are:

1/ Are my hawkBit setup steps correct?

2/ How can I configure/run swupdate (on clients) to perform the update: poll for new software, download, update, report status, ...

If my description isn't clear enough, please tell me.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

happy to see that you're trying out Hawkbit for your solution!

I have a few remarks:

- The `suricatta` parameter for GatewayToken is `-g`, and `-k` for TargetToken respectively.
- The `-g <GATEWAY_TOKEN>` needs to be set inside of the quotation marks
  see [SwUpdate Documentation](https://sbabic.github.io/swupdate/swupdate.html#suricatta-command-line-parameters)
  Example: `/usr/bin/swupdate -v -u '-t DEFAULT -u http://<domain>:<port> -i dev01 -g 76430e1830c56f2ea656c9bbc88834a3'`
- For the GatewayToken Authentication, you need to provide the generated token in System Config view, it is a generated hashcode that looks similar to this example here
- You can also authenticate each device/client separately using their own TargetToken.
  You can find more information in [the Hawkbit documentation](https://www.eclipse.org/hawkbit/concepts/authentication/)

Comment: Hi, 
After applying -g option, it's successful to update the device, but does have a problem. The update status isn't reflected on the hawkBit UI. Please advise. Here is the relavent log:

`
[TRACE] : SWUPDATE running :  [execute_shell_script] : Calling shell script /tmp/scripts/update.sh postinst : return with 0
[INFO ] : SWUPDATE successful ! SWUPDATE successful !
[TRACE] : SWUPDATE running :  [network_initializer] : Main thread sleep again !
[INFO ] : No SWUPDATE running :  Waiting for requests...
`

Sorry, I have to post in multiple comments.

Comment: `
[TRACE] : SWUPDATE running :  [channel_post_method] : Channel put operation returned HTTP status code 200.
[TRACE] : SWUPDATE running :  [server_create_details] : Detail 0 All Chunks Installed.
[TRACE] : SWUPDATE running :  [server_create_details] : Final details: "All Chunks Installed."
[TRACE] : SWUPDATE running :  [server_send_deployment_reply] : Reporting Installation progress for ID 3: none / proceeding / "All Chunks Installed."
`

Comment: `
[TRACE] : SWUPDATE running :  [channel_post_method] : Channel put operation returned HTTP status code 200.
[INFO ] : SWUPDATE running :  [server_install_update] : Update successful, executing post-update actions.
[DEBUG] : SWUPDATE running :  [server_install_update] : Post-update actions successfully executed.
[DEBUG] : SWUPDATE running :  [suricatta_wait] : Sleeping for 300 seconds.
`

Comment: `
[WARN ] : SWUPDATE running :  [server_has_pending_action] : An already installed update is pending testing, ignoring available update action.
[INFO ] : SWUPDATE running :  [server_has_pending_action] : Please restart SWUpdate to report the test results upstream.
[DEBUG] : SWUPDATE running :  [start_suricatta] : No pending action to process.
[DEBUG] : SWUPDATE running :  [suricatta_wait] : Sleeping for 300 seconds.
`

Re-run swupdate, the updating is re-run automatically and the above progress is repeated.
Distribution Set is assigned as "Forced" to Targets in the hawkBit UI.

Comment: I have a couple of questions:
- How is the agent (swupdate) connected to hawkbit? via DMF/DDI?
- What's the state in the UI? do you see any action status messages? or is the action stuck in status Pending?

Comment: 1/ swupdate run: `/usr/bin/swupdate -v -k /etc/public.pem -u '-t DEFAULT -u http://<domain>:<port> -i dev01 -g <gateway_token>'`. As per hawkBit doc, swupdate connects to hawkBit via DDI.  

2/ Action stuck in status Pending.  

3/ In hawkBit log, there are 2 error: `ERROR 30166 --- [executor-pool-2] o.s.s.s.TaskUtils$LoggingErrorHandler    : Unexpected error occurred in scheduled task` and `ERROR 30166 --- [ntContainer#0-1] o.s.a.r.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer : Failed to check/redeclare auto-delete queue(s).`

Comment: could you please rerun the hawkbit server with `logging.level.org.eclipse.hawkbit=DEBUG` environment variable and rerun the update?
It would be great if you can upload the logs somewhere so I can take a closer look

Comment: Please find the hawkBit and swupdate logs in my drive, and please let me know if you can't access these: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1SIWrRoRvaf283Z-B9w8jsEMMWV6VNjV-?usp=sharing

Comment: And please confirm the command to run hawkBit is correct: `java -jar ./hawkbit-runtime/hawkbit-update-server/target/hawkbit-update-server-0.3.0-SNAPSHOT.jar --spring.profiles.active=mysql logging.level.org.eclipse.hawkbit=DEBUG | tee hawkbit.log`

Comment: Sorry I'm very busy lately, I still didn't get a chance to look at the logs.
The command is mostly correct, only missing `--` before `logging.level.org.eclipse.hawkbit=DEBUG`.

Comment: That's OK, @Ahmed. I see that you're a very kind member.
I've uploaded the logs with `--logging.level.org.eclipse.hawkbit=DEBUG` on the same link. Please help to check if you have free time. Thank you!

Comment: I found that option when running swupdate: `-c, --confirm       Confirm update status to server: 1=AGAIN, 2=SUCCESS, 3=FAILED`. It looks like corresponding to the log: `Please restart SWUpdate to report the test results upstream.`

Comment: After updating done (log "Please restart SWUpdate to report the test results upstream." shown), manually terminate and re-run swupdate with "-c 2", it's successful to send the status to hawkBit. Now on hawkBit UI, I can see the status is "Status In Sync". But if I reboot the device, swupdate will not be run with "-c 2", then the status is not sent to hawkBit, in hawkBit UI, status will be "Status Pending"

Comment: @Huong, I have a similar situation. How did you manage to send status to hawkbit after reboot automatically. I can send status with "-c 2" manually